# Kafka Producer window won't allow me to add messages

Tags: powershell, apache-kafka

I'm running Kafka in Powershell.  I'm following a tutorial and trying to get my producer running again (I had to reboot my computer).

I ran the following command:

```
bin/windows/kafka-console-producer.bat --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic my-replicated-topic
```

But I can't enter my messages after that, even after I got my consumer running.  I'm running this in powershell.  I was able to get this working fine yesterday though.

I don't see any errors in my server.log but I'm not sure if I'm looking in the wrong spot.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up opening a command prompt window and typed:

```
"bin/windows/kafka-console-producer.bat" --broker-list localhost:9092 --topic my-replicated-topic
```

... and that worked.